# Group and count in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, group-by, mapreduce

I'm trying to group and count the amount of elements for each group in mongodb 2.0.1, but with no success so far.

My DB schema looks like :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4ece7544853b4b0941000000"),
    "ResultSet" : {
            "Results" : [
                    {
                            "quality" : 87,
                            "state" : "Franche-Comté"
                    }
            ]
    }
}
```

I've been trying all sort of methods, following different tutorials, but it is each time the same result : an only null group... which I don't understand why.

The best query I have written so far is the following :

```
db.extract_2000.group( {
            cond: { "ResultSet.Results.quality": {$exists: true} },
            key: {"ResultSet.Results.state": true}, 
            reduce: function(obj, glob) { glob.total++; glob.quality += obj.ResultSet.Results.quality },
            initial: { total: 0, quality: 0 },
            finalize: function(glob) {glob.avgquality = glob.quality / glob.total}
            })
```

Which returns (once again) :

```
[
        {
                "ResultSet.Results.state" : null,
                "total" : 2000,
                "quality" : NaN,
                "avgquality" : NaN
        }
]
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve -- somehow, you're trying to group embedded documents rather than documents? I don't think that will work, and the `$exists` condition won't be honored for each embedded document as far as I can see. Have you tried to use a simple object rather than an object with an array of subobjects? Are the counts (`total`) ok?

Comment: The total count is ok, I have 2000 documents in Database. I try to group per ResultSet.Results.state.

Comment: Well, you have 2000 *documents*, but that means your reduce function would have to iterate the array of subdocuments manually, doesn't it? The expression `obj.ResultSet.Results.quality` can't be evaluated inside the reduce function, I think: `Results` is an array, but you're using it like a plain object. I think this is the culprit.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I understand better my issue. When I use find(), mongodb manages very well the search of keys into an array, and I thought stupidly it would be the same in the reduce function. I tried a correction by doing changing reduce function into : function(obj, glob) { glob.total++; glob.quality += obj.ResultSet.Results[0].quality }, and it gives results. But I don't know (and don't think) if I can use array indices in the key argument.

Comment: I think you should not use subdocuments for your case. If you put those result objects in their own collection and use a separate object for each item, you should be better off. That also makes Map/reduce easier.

Answer (score 2):

This simply won't work as written. The key problem is here: `key: {"ResultSet.Results.state": true}`. `ResultSet.Results` is an array. When you ask for `ResultSet.Results.state` you are implying some type of `for` loop be done here. The `group` command is simply not capable of this.

Instead try the following M/R:

```
map = function() {
  // Note that we emit once per result
  foreach(var i in ResultSet.Results) {
    key = this.ResultSet.Results[i];
    value = { count: 1, 
      quality: this.ResultSet.Results[i].quality,
      avg_quality: 0
    };

    emit(key, value);
  }
}

reduce = function(key, values) {
  // note that results has same fields as emitted value
  var results = { count: 0, quality: 0, avg_quality: 0 };
  foreach(var i in values){
    results.count += values[i].count;
    results.quality += values[i].quality;
    // ignore avg_quality, we don't use it
  }
  return results;
}
```

You will also have to write a `finalize` for the average.

```
finalize = function(key, value) {
  if (value.count > 0)
    value.avg_quality = value.quality / value.count;

  return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The map function

```
map = function() {

    for(var i in this.Results) {
        emit(this.Results[i].state, 
            {quality: this.Results[i].quality, total: 1, avgquality: 0}
        );
    }
}
```

The reduce function

```
reduce = function(key, values) {
    var data = {quality: 0, total: 0, avgquality: 0};

    for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
        data.quality += values[i].quality;
        data.total += values[i].total;
    }
    return data;
}
```

In finalize function only calculate the avg.