# Group by in mongoDb without count

Tags: mongodb, date, group-by

I am working on a personnal project in which I need to group all my object by rounded dates up to the same hour. The thing is I don't want to agregate something.

I am having data store in following format in mongodb

```
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("4d663451d1e7242c4b68e000"), 
   "date" : "Mon Dec 27 2010 18:23:22 GMT+0000 (UTC)", 
   "name" : "james"
}, { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("4d6634514cb5cb2c4b69e000"), 
    "date" : "Mon Dec 27 2010 18:47:53 GMT+0000 (UTC)", 
    "name" : "bond", 
}, { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("4d6634514cb5cb2c4b69e000"), 
    "date" : "Mon Dec 27 2010 21:51:23 GMT+0000 (UTC)", 
    "name" : "bruce", 
}
```

I am looking for result in following format

```
{
   "rounded_date" : "Mon Dec 27 2010 18:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
   "items" : [ { 
           "_id" : ObjectId("4d663451d1e7242c4b68e000"), 
           "date" : "Mon Dec 27 2010 18:23:22 GMT+0000 (UTC)", 
           "name" : "james"
       }, { 
           "_id" : ObjectId("4d6634514cb5cb2c4b69e000"), 
           "date" : "Mon Dec 27 2010 18:47:53 GMT+0000 (UTC)", 
           "name" : "bond", 
       }
   ]
}, {
    "rounded_date": Mon Dec 27 2010 21:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC),
    "items" : [ { 
            "_id" : ObjectId("4d6634514cb5cb2c4b69e000"), 
            "date" : "Mon Dec 27 2010 21:51:23 GMT+0000 (UTC)", 
            "name" : "bruce", 
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: simply `count()` is good idea.. why you don't want to use that?

Comment: This is such a situation that you should aggregate the data using Map/Reduce.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8277698/1358004

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a good candidate for the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/) (new in mongoDB 2.2) the only caveat is you cannot create new dates on the fly at the moment, but you can extract the data you need from the date and group by it.

See the following example:

```
# Load the sample data
db.datetest.save({ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("4d663451d1e7242c4b68e000"), 
   "date" : ISODate("2010-12-27T18:23:22Z"),
   "name" : "james"
});

db.datetest.save({ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("4d6634514cb5cb2c4b69e000"), 
    "date" : ISODate("2010-12-27T18:47:53Z"),
    "name" : "bond", 
});

db.datetest.save({ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("4d6634514cb5cb2c4b69e001"), 
    "date" : ISODate("2010-12-27T21:51:23Z"),
    "name" : "bruce", 
});
```

Now perform an aggregation - first reproject the document into a useful format.

```
db.datetest.aggregate(
    {$project: {
        hour: {0: {"$year": "$date"},
               1: {"$month": "$date"},
               2: {"$dayOfMonth": "$date"},
               3: {"$hour": "$date"}},
        item: {
            _id: "$_id",
            date: "$date",
            name: "$name"
        }
    }},
    {$group: {
        _id: "$hour",
        items: {$push: "$item"}
    }}
)
```

The aggregation explained:

1. Here we create an `hour` subdocument with the year, month, day and hour extracted from the date.  We also create an `item` subdocument that we'll use in the group by.
2. Group by `hour` and push all the `item` documents into an `items` array.

And the results look like:

```
{
  "result" : [{
    "_id" : { "0" : 2010, "1" : 12, "2" : 27, "3" : 21 },
    "items" : [
      {
        "date" : ISODate("2010-12-27T21:51:23Z"),
        "name" : "bruce"
      }
    ]}, {
    "_id" : {"0" : 2010, "1" : 12, "2" : 27, "3" : 18},
    "items" : [{
        "date" : ISODate("2010-12-27T18:23:22Z"),
        "name" : "james"
      }, {
        "date" : ISODate("2010-12-27T18:47:53Z"),
        "name" : "bond"
      }
    ]}
  ],
  "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found another solution:

```
db.collection.group({
    cond: {'public': true},
    keyf: function(doc) {
        var date = doc.when
        date.setMinutes(0,0,0);
        return {'date' : date};
    },
    initial: { items:[] },
    reduce: function(doc, out) { out.items.push(doc); }
});
```

The thing is it's impossible to sort something after using a groupby. I think I will have to do that in client side.