# Count documents in collection MongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb

In MySQL to count rows in a table you would use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename`which to my understanding would be relatively fast as it just uses the tables metadata. What would be the way to do a similar thing in Mongo (I need to count users) and would it be as fast as MySQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group and count in MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268435/group-and-count-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count documents, use [db.collection.count](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/) in the mongo shell, or analogous methods in your driver. `count` can be used without parameters

```
db.mycollection.count()
```

to return the total number of documents in the collection, or it can be used with a query

```
db.mycollection.count({ "name" : "John", "age" : { "$lte" : 32", "$gte" : 24 } })
```

to count the number of documents matching a query. It generally works like `find` in how it uses table scans or indices, with the notable exception that, to count all of the records in a collection, it doesn't need to scan the whole collection since this number is kept track of anyway. This means it should be just as fast to count the total number of documents in a collection as to count the number of rows in a table in MySQL.